# Xamarin.Forms ScrollView adds extra space

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

My ScrollView adds extra spaces above the first child and under the last on my iPhone X. It is the blue gap above that Image. There is no padding or margin.

[image]

I gave the ScrollView a blue background to see it's dimensions better.
If I remove the ScrollView, the spacing also is gone. Here`s the code I am using

```
        <ScrollView>
            <!-- The MenuItems -->
            <Grid RowSpacing="0"
                  ColumnSpacing="0"
                  Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="350" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> -->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<animatedViews:SavannahCanvasView HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                  Grid.Row="0" />

                <Grid Grid.Row="2"
                      BackgroundColor="#fbc531">
                    <Image HeightRequest="100"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Aspect="Fill"
                           Source="{imageExtensions:ImageResource Source=Cheetah.Forms.Assets.Images.Background_Torque.png, TheAssembly=Cheetah.Forms}" />

                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 Margin="0,-100,0,0">

                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowMyPingsPageCommand}" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                        <Image Source="{imageExtensions:ImageResource Source=Cheetah.Forms.Assets.Images.Radar@256px.png, TheAssembly=Cheetah.Forms}"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               WidthRequest="150" />
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Style="{StaticResource WhiteLabel}"
                               Text="My Pings" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>
....
```

Is this maybe a bug or does it result by the iOS Statusbar rendering?
Also there is no spacing on my UWP project

Comment: Why do you use `Grid` in `Row=2`, if you don't have any `RowDefinition`s for it?
Replace it with `StackLayout` at least and see what would change.

Comment: Also change your Grid's RowDefinition's heights to `Auto`

Comment: It's because I need to layer the image and StackLayout inside the inner Grid. This could be done with a StackLayout, but I'm pretty sure changing this will not fix this issue, nor is there any advantage

Comment: You can also try to play around with margins of controls inside the Grid

Comment: Which Grid do you mean now? The Outer or Inner?

Comment: For both) Firstly for outer

Comment: So your suggestion is to set the outer grids margin to ```Margin="0,-20,0,0"```? But this will affect also the UWP projects margin, which will then be displaced. So I would need to check the OS type and also device version (iPhone X, XS, 8, ...), because there is also a spacing but with a smaller amount on an iPhone 8. This sounds like a hack and not a real solution to me

Comment: Have you solved your problem or tried my solution?

Answer (score 19):

After iOS 11, there is a property called `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` added to the scrollView.

From [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior?language=objc):

> This property specifies how the safe area insets are used to modify
>   the content area of the scroll view.

So, you need to use a `custom renderer` to config this property:

In code behiend:

```
public class myScrollView : ScrollView {

}
```

In custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(myScrollView), typeof(MyScrollviewRender))]

namespace App308.iOS
{
    class MyScrollviewRender : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                this.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
  <local:myScrollView>
        <!-- The MenuItems -->
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" RowSpacing="0"
                  ColumnSpacing="0"
                  Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">

            ....
        </Grid>
    </local:myScrollView>
```

Refer: [uiscrollviewcontentinsetadjustmentbehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewcontentinsetadjustmentbehavior?language=objc)

[custom-renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: You save my day

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Wasted a day chasing this, then I found your answer, and that solved it. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

Row 1 is missing

**Change this**

```xaml
<animatedViews:SavannahCanvasView HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="#fbc531">
```

**To this**

```xaml
<animatedViews:SavannahCanvasView HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#fbc531">`
```

Comment: Its not about that little gap between animatedView and the first grid, its the gap above the animatedView